# How to make it work, problem with 2 classes

Tags: c++, c++11

i have problem with my small project. I have two classes in it. 
Problem:

> error: 'Display' was not declared in this scope

Display is a class. Here is code:

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Display.h"
#include "Polynomial.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Polynomial prr;
    prr.show();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter x= ";
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"value for x="<<x<<endl<<"y="<<prr.value(x);

    Display aa; // this doesn't work
    //abc.show();

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
//Display.h
#ifndef DISPLAY_H
#define DISPLAY_H

class Display
{
    std::vector <vector <char> > graph;
    public:
        Display(int a, int b);
        //friend void lay(Polynomial abc,Display cba);
        //void show();
};

#endif // DISPLAY_H
```

I was thinking that maybe vectors are doing problems. I tested it without vectors, but it didn't change anthing.

```
//Display.cpp
#include "Display.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


Display::Display(int a, int b)
{
    //ctor
    if(a%2==0)
        a++;
    if(b%2==0)
        b++;

    vector <char> help;
    vector <char> mid;

    for(int i=0; i<b; i++)
    {
        mid.push_back('-');
        if(i==(b+1)/2)
            help.push_back('|');
        else
            help.push_back(' ');
    }

    for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        if(i==(a+1)/2)
            graph.push_back(mid);
        else
            graph.push_back(help);
    }
}
```

Now it's Polynomial class it's working fine, but Display class no, and i don't know why.

```
//Polynomial.h
#ifndef POLYNOMIAL_H
#define POLYNOMIAL_H
#include <vector>



//class Display;

class Polynomial
{...}


#endif // POLYNOMIAL_H
```

---

```
//Polynomial.cpp
#include "Polynomial.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

// constructors and methods here
// everything here working fine
```

Edit:
After few tries i am one step back,
Now in Display.h
i have error :

> error: 'vector' does not name a type

So i included vector lib.

But it didn't help.

Comment: According to your `display.h` file, you haven't defined a default constructor (or default arguments). Thus you need to call your constructor with arguments, too: `Display aa(12, 10);`.

Comment: Have you tried `Display aa(0,0);` ?

Comment: Please copy-paste the entire error message (instead of paraphrasing it, or copying half of it). Based on the example, that you show here, the error should state something about `Display` not having default constructor (or, rather, not having it declared).

Comment: Your Display.h shouldn't compile (e.g. using `vector` without `std::`). Either you have another Display.h in another directory that is getting included, or Display.h has unsaved changes in your editor, or your code is not the one shown here.

Comment: `include <vector>` in `Display.h`

Comment: Most likely the issue is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes).  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/625801/4342498) on how the code should be structured.

Comment: Please read about [mcve]. If you can reproduce the error without `Polynomial` then you can remove that entirely from the example

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius this is all nothing more

Comment: About [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...

Comment: @Placek070 I don't believe that -- the source code you provided must fail right when trying to define `Display` as @interjay explained.

Comment: @Placek070 If this is the single error you get (as in, there are no "File not found "`Display.h`"", before it), and this is the code you are trying to compile - I don't believe you.

Comment: @Aconcagua Nothing change

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius https://imgur.com/a/zdQ9sde look

Comment: @interjay I'll change the name of class, maybe you are right

Comment: @Placek070 1) What version of GCC are you using? 2) How are you compiling such a code? 3) When I try to compile the code, that is copy-pasted from your example: [I get very different list of errors](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xVI8F7ERlK7tDqzy). Which makes me think, that you aren't compiling the same code, as you are showing us. For example, did you save the files, that you are trying to compile?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius that is strange, but after i change the name of class, i have more errors (the same like you).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Error Number 1:**

You defined a constructor with 2 parameters

```
Display(int a, int b);
```

But when you call

```
Display aa;
```

Compiler try to instantiate a Display object with a default constructor, that you disabled defining a custom costructor;

you have 2 possibilities:

Adding a default constructor like

```
Display() = default;
```

or

```
Display() { /* do whatever you want to init with default parameter */}
```

Instantiate your variable using the constructor you defined

```
Display aa{0,0};
```

**Error number 2:**

```
std::vector < std::vector <char> > graph;
```

You declared `vector<char>` instead of `std::vector<char>`

**[See a Live Example](http://cpp.sh/562vp)**

Comment: i know about it, but this don't change anything and you have to use ( ) not { }.

Comment: @Placek070 both your statement are wrong. That solve your issue as you can see in the live example and using brace initialization is totally fine, and a more solid syntax

Comment: Wait..You are right ! thanks, i am a newbie so please forgive me. I just forgot about std in Display.h and this ^^

Comment: @Placek070 I was already aware of your second issue (the missing std), I pointed out that too.

Answer (score -1):

One reason is that your `Display` class has no default constructor, considering you're creating object like `Display aa;` . A default constructor is the constructor that has no arguments. Default constructors are provided implicitly by compiler as synthesized default constructor only if you don't provide any constructors to your class. If you provide your own constructors to your class, you must also explicitly provide a default constructor.  So in your case, you should actually create Display object like this `Display aa(argument, argument);` by providing arguments. However, If you want to create object like `Display aa;` then add either `Display () { }` or `Display() = default;` in your `Display.h` file.

Considering you created object like the way I described but still getting an error, another reason could be that you're not compiling the source file that contains the `Display (int,int);` constructor definition (not just declaration as you did in your header file) along with the source file that contains the `main` function. If you did that but still getting an error in compilation, then I would assume it is a compiler issue and try adding a forward declaration `class Display;` which should compile the code.  But the definition of `Display` has to be within the visible range of `main` function otherwise a forward declaration would do nothing.

In any case, you have to make sure the definition of your class is within the visible range of the `main` function that creates the class object. A class type with only declaration without a definition is called incomplete type and you cannot create an object of incomplete type. So the declaration of your `Display (int,int);` constructor in the `Display.h` is not enough. You also need a definition of that within the visible range of `main` function. You can either do that in the same file as main, same file as header, or a separate source file (which is the best practice) that has the complete definition of Display class, its data members, and member functions. However, you must make sure to compile that source file along with the source file containing main.

Comment: That won't let you construct a `Display` object, and it shouldn't be needed if you include Display.h.